# Update Airflow XCOM value in Database

Tags: python, airflow

How can I update any value in the XCOM table with:

```
session.query(XCom)
```

Is there any option like the following?

```
session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.dag_id == "mydag123").update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question:

```
session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.dag_id == "mydag123") \
.update({XCom.value:b'new value'})
```